# How does the songwriting "jam session" work?

Tags: jamming

When trying to understand this stage of creation, I read "members play instruments freely to experiment with melodies, chord progressions, and rhythms". But how playing two, or even multiple melodies in parallel, leave alone "freely" could result in anything else than total chaos where nothing could be heard? If I would say mix multiple finished songs to be played in parallel tracks, the output likely will not sound like any music. Do they have any rules for that?

Comment: It's actually harder to do it alone. Jam sessions start with simple ideas, probably soloing/vamping over a basic agreed pattern. Then musicians feed off each other's ideas and notice potential new building blocks that could turn into melodies, progressions and form. They also somewhat "criticize" each other in good spirit and thereby establish common aesthetic.  As they repeat this, they can bounce off from higher and higher levels, and sometimes start with complicated stuff that gets distilled down.

Comment: It seems like this question is about it can ever be possible for multiple musicians to jam together and make something nice. If that's the case, you might take the word "songwriting" out of the question. Often people jam in situations where the goal isn't to capture what they do and save it to be "a song" that can be played again. Improvised guitar solos, free jazz, etc. all make jamming work but don't "write a song" as a result.

Comment: "If I would say mix multiple finished songs to be played in parallel tracks, the output likely will not sound like any music." - for what it's worth, renowned composers have done almost exactly that. See for example Charles Ives, who was inspired by childhood experiences of hearing multiple marching bands play at the same time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niUXRKdpeZ0&t=520s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe that's why a 'Songwriting jam session' is not encountered very often!  'Jam session' more typically means a group of players extemporizing on an agreed song or chord sequence.  There HAVE been experiments with completely 'free-form' improvisation where everyone just plays whatever comes into their heads, but yes, it generally results in chaos!

But yes, it could work like this.  Bass player comes up with a lick, drummer joins in, guitar suggests taking it round a certain chord sequence, vocalist improvises a melody...   But it really has to start with SOMETHING, not just everyone playing their own idea regardless!

Comment: Seems to be the norm in some French circles. But it certainly isn't about song writing, more about a jam session, that sometimes (if lucky) develops into something palatable.

Comment: @Tim I confirm. That might explain why I have troubles finding these king of jam abroad...

Comment: @Tom - for king of jam do we translate as kind of jams? Or is confiture more in keeping?

Comment: @Tim, yes... My autocorrect sometimes gets creative ;)